# what are the main differences between spring security in built JWT authentication vs when we use any JWT dependency and provide its implementation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

For e.g when we use "io.jsonwebtoken" for JWT authentication then we make "sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)" session creation policy stateless but what's the scenario when we are using inbuilt spring security JWT authentication, there we don't make the session as stateless. So what exact difference between using any other JWT dependency over an inbuilt mechanism of spring security.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security's Resource Server support uses `JwtAuthenticationToken`, which is marked as [`@Transient`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9729):

```java
@Transient
public class JwtAuthenticationToken {
    // ...
}
```

This means that it won't be stored in the session regardless of the session management policy.

Because of that, there is no need to declare the session creation policy as stateless if you are only using `oauth2ResourceServer()`.

If you integrated with JJWT in such a way that your authentication provider also emitted a `JwtAuthenticationToken` (or if your `Authentication` were annotated with `@Transient`), you would also in that case not need to specify a stateless session creation policy.